# Limit Managed Service Account to only run certain service

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-management, user-accounts, windows-service

I've started learning about Managed Service Accounts in Windows. As I understand it, such accounts make password management easier and the accounts can be limited to be used on certain machines.
You then can start every Windows Service you want with that user.

Suppose following scenario:

1. SQL Server Service runs with a Managed Service Account
2. That user is SA on the SQL Server
3. Some malicious user creates a service on the same machine and runs it with the same Managed Service Account. This would be possible because no password is required when setting the "logon user" of the service
4. That service can now connect to the SQL Server as SA.

Without Managed Service Accounts, one would need the password to be able to connect to the SQL Server. With Managed Service Accounts, starting a service with the same user as the SQL Server Service and you are able to connect.
It looks easier to misuse a Managed Service Account than a regular AD user.

Is it possible to make sure the Managed Service Account can only be used with a certain service?
Or am I missing something?

Comment: Don't you need admin privileges to change the running user for a service? Passwords for users running service are stored in HKLM Security on the machine also, so if an attacker gets access to that, he has the password for reusage on multiple systems. While with GSMA accounts he can only do stuff on the compromised server.

Comment: Correct.  The appropriate security control for this is to limit Administrator access on the SQL server.  Anybody with the ability to misuse the gMSA on that machine would already have sufficient access to the service to do far worse than just manipulate SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows accounts cannot be limited to a specific service, and that includes MSA's.